# Copy XML2 data to XML1

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have one XML1 as follows.

```
-<Master> 
 <UserDetails>
  <UserName>Michael</UserName>
  <Password>Password</Password>
 </UserDetails>
 <Height>155</Height>
 <Weight>150lb</Weight> 
 <OtherDetails>
  <Phone>987654327</Phone>
  <Email>mich.int@ymail.com</Email>
 </UserDetails>
 <company>155</company>
 <address>155 beecroft</address>
</Master>
```

My other XML2 is

```
  -<Master> 
     <Company>
      <Name>CCD</Name>
      <ID>122975</ID>
     </Company>
     <Employee>15500</Employee>
     <Shift>No</Shift> 
     <OtherDetails>
      <Phone>020 55667354</Phone>
      <Email>ccd.int@ymail.com</Email>
     </OtherDetails>
     <address>155 Bay street </address>
     <Time>10.50</Time>
    </Master>
```

Now i want to append/copy data in my XML1 from XML2. After node `<Height>` in XML1 i want to append data from XML2 after node `<Employee>`.

My final output should be.

```
-<Master> 
 <UserDetails>
  <UserName>Michael</UserName>
  <Password>Password</Password>
 </UserDetails>
 <Height>155</Height>
 <Shift>No</Shift> 
 <OtherDetails>
  <Phone>020 55667354</Phone>
  <Email>ccd.int@ymail.com</Email>
 </OtherDetails>
 <address>155 Bay street </address>
 <Time>10.50</Time>
</Master>
```

I tried this code but getting exception of object reference not set to an instance.

```
 Dim PROD As XmlNode = XML1.SelectSingleNode("/MASTER")
 Dim PAG As XmlNode = XML2.SelectSingleNode("/MASTER")
       For Each node As XmlNode In PROD.SelectNodes("SHIFT |...... other nodes")
                PAG.AppendChild(XML1.ImportNode(node, True))
            Next
```

I tried other methods also but didnt work, Please suggest how we can do it in VB.Net
Please note i am using XMLDocument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
Dim height = XML1.SelectSingleNode("/Master/Height")
'select all nodes after <Height>'
Dim nodesAfterHeight = XML1.SelectNodes("/Master/Height/following-sibling::*")
'select all nodes after <Employee>'
Dim nodesAfterEmployee = XML2.SelectNodes("/Master/Employee/following-sibling::*")

'remove all nodes after <Height> in XML1'
For Each node As XmlNode In nodesAfterHeight
    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node)
Next
'add all nodes after <Employee>'
For Each node As XmlNode In nodesAfterEmployee
    height.ParentNode.InsertAfter(XML1.ImportNode(node, True), height)
Next
```